# Using Mutation in R

Tags: r, stat

I am trying to create x amount of new columns based on values of this data frame. For instance, if the value equals two, I want to create two new columns with values from a function and the remaining columns to be zero. If the value equals one, I want to create one new column and insert values from the same function.

The function to go in the columns are something along the lines of x*y

```
Value  Number1   Number2 Number3 Number4
2       10000   10000        0       0
1       12000     0          0       0
3       12000   10000       12000    0      
1               
1               
3           
1               
0
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
#Binomial Distribution 
NumberofBids <- rbinom(10 ,4,0.5)
BidsNumSim <- data.frame(sample(NumberofBids, size=1000, replace=T))

names(BidsNumSim)[1] = "CompNum"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a function called `myfun` which returns the numbers that you need to fill. For simplicity, here we can define it as -

```
myfun <- function() {
  seq(10, 100, 10)
}
```

We can add new columns to the dataframe by -

```
n <- max(BidsNumSim$CompNum)

BidsNumSim[paste0('Number', seq_len(n))] <- t(sapply(BidsNumSim$CompNum, 
           function(x) c(myfun()[seq_len(x)], rep(0, n - x))))

BidsNumSim

#    CompNum Number1 Number2 Number3
#1         2      10      20       0
#2         2      10      20       0
#3         1      10       0       0
#4         3      10      20      30
#5         3      10      20      30
#6         1      10       0       0
#7         1      10       0       0
#8         3      10      20      30
#9         3      10      20      30
#...
#...
```